# Angular UI-Grid Awesome Bootstrap Checkboxes not functioning properly

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on adding custom CSS styling for my checkboxes via Awesome Bootstrap Checkboxes and have them actually showing up in the grids with them initially being checked or unchecked properly via JSON data being read...

the issue is when I go to change the value. The values are updating properly from  when shown to  when hidden.

However, instead of just the checkmark disappearing in the checkbox, the entire checkbox disappears and the only way for me to get it back is to change the value of the  back to ui-grid-cell-focus manually through F12 debugger in the browser.

It appears something is not set up right with them, but I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what he issue is yet...any help would be appreciated.

Cell Template:

```
cellTemplate: 

`<!-- .blueCheckbox --> <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"> <input type="checkbox" class="ng-scope" value="true" name="select_item" ng-model="row.entity.Name" /> <label></label> </div> <!-- end .blueCheckbox -->,`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got them working...Had to enable the checkboxes and move them underneath the overlay and they worked fine...weird because its totally different from how it normally works...